# Converting String into Float Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, xcode4, xcode4.2

I want to retrieve the latitude and the longitude of a data which is in a string right now. For using it, it has to be converted into a float so I can use it here instead of the float-numbers:

```
//Create a region 

mapview.mapType = MKMapTypeSatellite;
MKCoordinateRegion newRegion;
newRegion.center.latitude = 47.808435,
newRegion.center.longitude = 9.643743;
newRegion.span.latitudeDelta = 0.00472;
newRegion.span.longitudeDelta = 0.006899;

CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
coordinate.latitude = 47.808435;
coordinate.longitude = 9.643743;
```

I just know how to convert a string into data, but I have no idea how to convert it into a float. Does anybody know?

Comment: How it is possible that `maplatitude` is both an image (you assign it to `storyimageView`) **and** a float?

Comment: My fault. I just realized that I copied wrong. Will fix it so nobody will be confused.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you have an NSString instance containing a valid floating-point number's string representation, you can use this:

```
float number = [anNSString floatValue];
```

Comment: great, this works fine and was pretty easy. So in my case, I did `float number1 = [mymap.latitude floatValue];` for `    newRegion.center.latitude = number1;`. Thanks!

Comment: oops, I accepted it and then accidentially un-accepted ^^'' Done.